# Sorting the two highest numbers in an array

Tags: java

I'm sorry to ask, but I'm having trouble with an exercise in my book, and I am unsure how to fix it. After entering the student's name and score, I am to find the highest and second highest score. However I cannot find a proper way to find the two highest scores.

The current way I use works, but fails the user enters scores from low to high, such as 70, 80, and 90. If done 90, 80, and 70, it sorts the numbers appropriately.

Is there anything I could change/do/read to put me on the right path?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // For finding highest scores with corresponding array
        double firstHighest = 0;
        int firstEntry = 0;
        double secondHighest = 0;
        int secondEntry = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter the number of students: ");
        int studentCount = input.nextInt();

        // Length of arrays set
        int[] studentScores = new int[studentCount];
        String[] studentName = new String[studentCount];

        // Go through loop to set scores and names of each student
        for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a student name: ");
            studentName[i] = input.next();
            System.out.print("Enter a student score: ");
            studentScores[i] = input.nextInt();
            }

        // Find out the highest and second highest scores
        // Problem with secondHighest/Entry
        for (int i = 0; i < studentScores.length; i++) {
            if (studentScores[i] > firstHighest) {
                secondHighest = firstHighest;
                firstHighest = studentScores[i];
                firstEntry = i;
        } else if (studentScores[i] > secondHighest) {
                secondHighest = studentScores[i];
                secondEntry = i;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Top two students: ");
    System.out.println(studentName[firstEntry] + "'s score is " + firstHighest);
    System.out.println(studentName[secondEntry] + "'s score is " + secondHighest);
    }
}
```

As always, I thank you for any help that you can provide.

Comment: I suggest either using the debugger to inspect the values of your variables as your program progresses, or adding a load of `println` statements to display these intermediate values.  That way you can compare what you expect to happen with what's actually happening.

Comment: What is not working exactly? (wrong output, error message,...)

Comment: just sort your array in descending order by score and pick first two entries (sorry, i'm in a "Captain Obvious" mood)

Comment: @VictorSorokin That's very inefficient it takes `O(nlog(n))` to sort, in the best algorithm, and it only takes `O(n)` to find the two highest elements.

Comment: @VictorSorokin The problem with that method (it did cross my mind) is that I would lose the pairing of the name with the score.

Comment: @talnicolas It appears to order the numbers and names incorrectly if scores are entered in a ascending order.

Comment: @CaseyWeed it won't lose pairing if you place student together with his/her score into one class, which is `Comparable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here

```
    if (studentScores[i] > firstHighest) {
        secondHighest = firstHighest;
        firstHighest = studentScores[i];
        firstEntry = i;
    }
```

you successfully update the values for both secondHighest and firstHighest but you don't fix secondEntry;

you need to add

```
secondEntry = firstEntry;
```

before

```
firstEntry = i;
```

Comment: This has fixed the issue entirely.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you just forgot to update `secondEntry` when you get a new highest score. Before the line:

```
            firstEntry = i;
```

Try adding:

```
            secondEntry = firstEntry;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more than 1 ways to solve this problem. The most intuitive way would be akin to picking up a hand of cards (i.e insertion sort). Think of the inputs as a continuous list of cards. It doesn't really matter what order they come in as most players will sort them going from lowest to highest (or the other way around).

So in your input loop:

```
 while(...some_condition_that_ensures_more_input){
     //this can be a list for instance, which you keep in order
     list =  insert_into_correct_place(input);                                             
 }

 /**
   Assuming 
   a)you sort from lowest to highest 
   b)there is more than 1 input entered):
 */
 highest = list.get(list.length()-1)
 second_highest = list.get(list.length()-2)
```

Another intuitive way (and actually faster) way is to just keep track of two variables:

```
 int [] highest = {Integer.MIN_VALUE(), Integer.MIN_VALUE()};      
 while(...){
      highest = replace_lowest(input, highest);
 }
```

---

```
 /**
  * arr is sorted from lowest to highest : arr[0] is always <= arr[1] 
  */
 int [] replace_lowest(int input, int [] arr){          
     //Case 0 : input is less than both the highest 2 numbers
     //         or is equal to one of them
     if (input < arr[0] || input == arr[0] || input == arr[1]) { return arr; }

     //Case 1 : input is greater than one of the highest 2, but not both
     if (input > arr[0] && input < arr[1]) { arr[0] = input; return arr; }

     //Case 2 : input is greater than both of the highest 2 numbers
     second_highest = arr[1]; arr[0] = arr[1]; arr[1] = input;
     return arr;      
 }
```

The first approach is a bit more flexible (it would allow you to pick out X highest numbers instead of just two). The second approach is faster if you know that you will never have to readjust the number of output variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `java.util.Arrays` class and its `sort()` method. Here's what the code might look like:

```
Arrays.sort(studentScores);
int firstHighest = studentScores[studentScores.length - 1];
int secondHighest = studentScores[studentScores.length - 2];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But then he would lose the score-name pairing.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote you a method with the help of an inner class; it returns an array, the first element is the Student with the heighest score, the second Student the one with the second score.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class StudentSort {

static class Student {
        Student(int score, String name) {
        this.score = score;
        this.name = name;
        }
        int score;
        String name;
    }

    private static Student[] test(int[] studentScores, String[] studentNames) {
        Student[] students = new Student[studentScores.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < studentScores.length; i++) {
        students[i] = new Student(studentScores[i], studentNames[i]);
        }
        Arrays.sort(students, new Comparator<Student>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
            return new Integer(o1.score).compareTo(o2.score);
        }
    });
        return new Student[]{students[0], students[1]};
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] studentScores = new int[] {5, 9, 7};
        String[] studentNames = new String[]{"Jan", "Bert", "Piet"};
        Student[] students = test(studentScores, studentNames);
        System.out.println("heighest: " + students[0].name + ": " + students[0].score);
        System.out.println("second: " + students[1].name + ": " + students[1].score);
    }
}
```